# Should the measurement errors of data included in the curve fitting of these data?

Tags: statistics, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, data-analysis

I am working to fit some data with a Gaussian model, the data comes from an experiment with a measurement error in the same order of the data points at the tails, both are in order $10^{-6}$, what I do is try to minimize $f$ where $$f=model-data.$$ My question is: Should I account for the measurement errors in the fitting? if yes, how can I modify $f$ to account for it?

** The peak value is in order $10^{-3}$, the data is a set of 20 points, where 3 points at each side of the tails have measurement errors in the same order as the data point itself.

Comment: Yes, if you assume that the error is propotional to the standard deviation. It then becomes a weighted regression.

Comment: Thank you, I modified f as $$f=(model-data)/error,$$ but when I try to find $\chi^2/dof$, I got a very small value near zero, what is the best way to scale $f$ so that i get value of $\chi^2/dof$ around 1, and if I compare between different models, is there any other parameters to use to determine which one is the best?